# printf Function not giving output in C

Tags: c

I am an absolute newbie, and I am learning to code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    char characterName[] = "Khan";
    int characterYear = 2022;
    float characterScore = 8.8;
    char characterGrade = 'A';
    printf("%s passed out of college in %d and had a grade of %s i.e. a score of %f\n",characterName,characterYear,characterGrade,characterScore);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me with this — I was just trying to incorporate all simple data types in one line (for reference) and after I run the program there is no output whatsoever, it just exits! It didn't happen when I had fewer data types in the line.

P.S. This might be the dumbest ever question ever asked on Stack Overflow, but please forgive if I am dumb/silly :)

Comment: Enable warnings with -Wall or /Wall and you'll see the problem immediately

Comment: regarding: `float characterScore = 8.8;`  This is trying to push a `double` literal into a `float` variable.  Not a good idea.  A double literal can be rewritten as a `float` literal by appending a `f` to the end of the literal.  I.E.:  8.8 --> 8.8f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is wrong:

`characterGrade` has type `char` and you want to print it using `%s` format which requires `char *` parameter. It has to be `%c` instead:

```
"%s passed out of college in %d and had a grade of %c i.e. a score of %f\n"
```